# Prompt user to select required folder from a set of folders

Tags: bash

I want to list the current folders in the same dir and display it to the user asking them to enter a number to select the correct folder.

```
Please select a Folder eg, 1,2,3.
1. Folder Name 1 
2. Folder 2
3. Folder 3.
```

I would like to also be able to convert the input eg 1. Back to the actual folder name so I can

```
cd ./$foldername/
```

I tried but it was not successful

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Please select folder:\n"
select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break;  done
cd "$d" && pwd
```

It throws an error  "select: not found" 
Why is it so? where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you make an attempt?

Comment: yes...but it failed somewhere

Comment: printf "Please select folder:\n"
select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break;  done
cd "$d" && pwd

Comment: Your shebang line has a problem - remove the space after `#!`

Comment: Which shell is `/bin/sh`? Is it `bash` or `dash` or some other shell? Which platform are you on? On macOS Sierra specifically, and on other platforms I've used, `#! /bin/bash` with a space would be no problem. I created a script with shebang `#! /usr/local/bin/sqlcmd -dstores -f` and an SQL `select` statement in the body.  The shell complained about the syntax of the `select` (perfectly reasonably; it uses `from` instead of `in`), but when I ran the script `./sel.sh`, it picked up the correct interpreter and generated the correct output data. So, I remain to be convinced the shebang's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you're after?

```
#put directories into an array
folder_list=($(find /$foldername/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec basename {} \;))
#loop the output to prevent errors in the user's input
while true; do
    #clear the screen for each loop iteration
    tput clear
    #print the contents of the array and number them
    printf '%s\n' "${folder_list[@]}" | cat -n
    #read user input and store response as variable
    read -p $'Please select a Folder eg, 1,2,3.\n>' REPLY
    #check if variable is zero or not a number, if so restart the loop
    #check if variable is within the range of array content
    if ((REPLY)) && ((REPLY<=${#folder_list[@]})); then
        #if it is then print it out and break the loop
        echo ${folder_list[$((--REPLY))]}
        break
    fi
    echo "Invalid response"
done
```

It's worth pointing out, that this method is not portable because of the double parentheses.

Sorry about all the edits, the code wasn't efficient enough for me.

Comment: I actually want to do a script to print size,modified time and name of files being loaded from different folders.So for that I want my script to prompt the user to select the folder from the current directory.

Comment: That's fine then, just take the array result like I did and do stuff with it like `du` or `cd` into it.  The original question, to which I was answering, could have been a bit more specific though.